# Confused about geometric distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, games, geometric-distribution

So I have a game that follows a geometric distribution.

There is a probability, $p$, of winning a round. If the player wins, he earns \$1,000. **As soon as there is a win, the game ends.**

If the player loses, then he can keep playing.

However, each round costs \$100 to play.

Is the expected payoff of this game therefore:

\$1,000 - \$100*(1/$p$)

or is it

1,000 $p (1-p)^\frac{1-p}{p}$ - 100*(1/$p$)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the player always keeps playing until they win:

E(# rounds) = $\frac{1}{p}$

Since price per round is \$100, the cost to play a complete game is \$100* $\frac{1}{p}$. And we know eventually the player gets paid exactly $1000.

To calculate profit = Money paid to player - money paid by player

So, 1000- ($\frac{1}{p}*100)$ would be the correct expected payoff or profit.

Comment: Why would it not be:

1,000 $p (1-p)^\frac{1-p}{p}$ - 100*(1/$p$) 

There are $K=\frac{1-p}{p}$ rounds of failure, so there is a probability of success of $p (1-p)^K$. You wouldn't multiply the \$1,000 by this?

Comment: My answer assumes the player keeps playing until they win, and they can only win once per game (which is what I understood your scenario to be). So the probability of winning eventually is 1, so the player will get paid 1000 at the end of every game. The only variable here is the cost of playing the game which is a product of cost per round (\$100) and rounds played. The expected number of rounds played is $\frac{1}{p}$. So the expected cost is \$100 * 1/p.